# Is it right to say "I don't live here naturally?

Tags: grammar, phrase-requests, syntactic-analysis

Can someone confirm or correct my grammar?

Someone was asking me where I live. But my current address isn't my permanent one. So I answered:

> "I don't live here naturally."

Was that correct? Or is there a more normal way to express this idea in English?

Comment: Permanently is the word to use.

Comment: That’s not my permanent address.  “naturally” leads me to wonder how one lives *unnaturally*... and makes me think maybe I don’t want to know.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, 'naturally' doesn't make sense in the sentence and could be taken as meaning that you are not indigenous to the country you are currently in.

If someone asked where I live and my current address was not my permanent one, I would explain, "I live in (permanent address), but i am currently (staying lodging, renting) in (current address)".

If you were living in the UK and someone asked where you lived, it is quite common to say, "I'm not from around here".